# Freeform - allowed file types

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads

I'm using Freeform 4.1.8 and EE 2.8.1 . I have a Freeform form with an upload file field.  It's uploading all files ok, except docx .

I've checked that docx is in the mimes.php file, the upload directory is set to all file types.  I've tried adding in allowed_file_types="*" to Freeform but it's still not working.

My Freeform code looks like this:

```
 {exp:freeform:form collection="applications"
  return="careers/apply/thank-you"
  notify_admin="yes"
  admin_notify="email@address.com"
  admin_cc_notify="email@address.com"
  template="admin_notify"
  send_attachment="yes"
  file_upload="uploaded_CVs"
  allowed_file_types="*"
  send_user_email="no"
  notify_user="no"
  require_captcha="yes" }
```

My File upload Field looks like this:

```
 {freeform:field:upload_cv show="1" allowed_file_types="*"}
```

[image: The error message I'm getting]

Edit: I set up a Channel Form to see if I could upload docx files through that, and it worked fine.  It looks like it's just Freeform that won't let me upload them.

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify: When you say "not working" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to include a screenshot.  I just get the screen above with the message.

Answer (score 1):

Freeform 4.2.1 and 4.2.2 brought a number of bug fixes for upload handling (some reported by me).  See [the change log](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/change_log/) for details.

I'm not certain what you are seeing is a FreeForm bug but I would definitely recommend updating before going too deep into troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help.  I've updated to 4.2.2 but the issue is still there.  All files upload correctly, except .docx

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a simple fix, In Freeform > Fields > Field Settings > Allowed File Types I had dox instead of docx.